# How to use an Interface to access classes that implemented it?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, interface, polymorphism

Update: My initial plan was to use it for upcasting and downcasting. I just wanted my method to be able to return different class based on different responses from the server.

I'm trying to understand advanced use of interface. Lets say I have an inter face like bellow:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{

}
```

I have two class which implement the above interface like bellow.

```
public class A:IMyInterface
{
    public string AName { get; set; }
}

public class B : IMyInterface
{
    public string BName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have four methods like below:

```
public IMyInterface CreateRawResponse()
{
    if (condition)
    {
        return new A
        {
            AName = "A"
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return new B
        {
            BName = "B"
        };
    }
}

public string CreateResponse(IMyInterface myInterface)
{
    return myInterface. // I would like to access the properties of the     parameter, since its actually a class
}
public string CreateResponseForA(A a)
{
    return a.AName;
}

public string CreateResponseForB(B b)
{
    return b.BName;
}
```

Finally I'm trying to call the methods like this:

```
var obj = new Program();
var KnownResponse = obj.CreateRawResponse(); // Lets say I know I will get type A
var test1 = obj.CreateResponseForA(KnownResponse); //But I can't call like this, because CreateResponseForA() is expecting IMyInterface as parameter type.
var UknownResponse = obj.CreateRawResponse(); // Lets say I don't know the response type, all I know is it implemented IMyInterface

var test2 = obj.CreateResponse(UknownResponse); // I can call the method but can access the properties of the calling type in CreateResponse() mehtod.
```

How to handle this kind of situation? I believe there might some design pattern to solve this, but I'm not used to design patterns. Any advice would be really helpful.

Comment: If you want a property to be available in an interface, add it to that interface.

Comment: let interface have common property `interface IMyInterface { string Name { get; } }`

Comment: Your interface is empty.  It needs to have an accessible property that is common to the classes that implement it, in order for it to be used in the way that you want.  Otherwise, your interface is quite simply pointless.

Comment: Think of an interface as a common feature shared by many things like the USB port - it defines an interface and you can plug in a printer, a phone and many more devices. Just because they all agree on common interface.

Comment: If you are using an interface as a parameter in a method then all the properties and methods you are expected to use within the method should be contained in the interface and then implemented in the classes implementing the interface. That is the point of using interfaces in the first place.

Comment: Sorry guys, I had common properties, but in my interface I actually marked it as class & then was trying to access the properties, which I couldn't. Then I got confused. Sorry again.

Comment: This is essentially a factory pattern

Comment: An interface is a contract that guarantees that all classes that implement it will implement the properties and methods defined in the interface. So a method that accepts an interface knows that, at a minimum, the concrete class passed to it will implement  the properties and methods in the interface, and those will be available.

Comment: I know, but got confused due to silly mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface should have member common to all that implement it

```
public interface IMyInterface {
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Thus

```
public class A:IMyInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B : IMyInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which then mean that you situation becomes.

```
public IMyInterface CreateRawResponse()
{
    if (condition)
    {
        return new A
        {
            Name = "A"
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return new B
        {
            Name = "B"
        };
    }
}

public string CreateResponse(IMyInterface myInterface)
{
    return myInterface.Name;
}
public string CreateResponseForA(A a)
{
    return a.Name;
}

public string CreateResponseForB(B b)
{
    return b.Name;
}
```

Which could also then be refactored to

```
public string CreateResponse(IMyInterface myInterface)
{
    return myInterface.Name;
}
public string CreateResponseForA(A a)
{
    return CreateResponse(a);
}

public string CreateResponseForB(B b)
{
    return CreateResponse(b);
}
```